# How to load Angular.js form to jsFiddle?

Tags: css, angularjs, jsfiddle

I try to load [that's form](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation) to `jsFiddle` .

It has two external files - `app.js` and `bootstrap.min.css` - I added both them to my `GitHub` and then feed its url as External Resources in the `jsFiddle` .

Finally I copy&paste the  scope to the appropriate scope in the `jsFiddle`.

**[Here the result of that jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/EfEuw/2/)**

As you can see there is no affect of the CSS and `app.js` (cause `alert`) in this jsFiddle .

How to make it work , mean -make it same as in the attached [form link](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation) ?

**Update:**

Following the suggested soluions - I fixed the CSS URL and copied the app.js content to the javascript scope .

http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/gnQ4p/

Now it seems the CSS works , but the Angular validation isn't working (just prompt the error line even before I change its fields) .

Any solution  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like in this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/EfEuw/3/

The bootstrap source url is `//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css` so all you need to do is add it do external resources.

If you are using a fiddle, I would suggest just using the same sources that the examples use, because they are already hosted on the web.

Comment: @URL87 not sure where the source for app.js is, but you can also just fork it or create a new page to edit from plunker.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using the wrong URLs for linking the external resources. They should be:

1. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/urielz1987/apps.js/master/bootstrap.min.css
2. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/urielz1987/apps.js/master/app.js

However, JSFiddle itself will tell you right away that if you link the above 2 files, they will probably not work because GitHub is not a CDN.

You should find another place to host those resources and link from there or simply copy/paste their code inside the Javascript section.